# Asp.Net Mvc Remote Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate

Então, estou tentando implementar o `RemoteAttribute`, porém ao clicar no botão `submit`, não está dando o `post` em minha página.

Meu Controller

```
public class TesteRemoteController : Controller
{
    // GET: TesteRemote
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new TesteRemoteViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Nome,Observacao")] TesteRemoteViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //salvar no banco

            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    public JsonResult IsNomeAvailable(string nome, int Id)
    {
        //verificar no banco se o nome não é duplicado
        if (true)
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        string suggestedUID = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "O upload {0} já foi cadastrado.", nome);

        return Json(suggestedUID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Meu Model

```
public class TesteRemoteViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("IsNomeAvailable", "TesteRemote", AdditionalFields = "Id")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Observacao { get; set; }
    }
```

Minha View

```
    @model WebApplication5.Models.TesteRemoteViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TesteRemote";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                TesteRemote
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {

                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        @Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.Id)

                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Observacao)
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Observacao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Observacao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default" />
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Index")" class="btn btn-default">Voltar</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Então, acredito que o meu principal problema estava em dar Post duas vezes com o mesmo dado preenchido no campo Nome usando o IE, pois tem a tal de Cache, pra resolver só adicionei o `[OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None)]` no meu método que uso no `RemoteAttribute`.

Comment: Outra coisa muito importante é no método `Create()` já retornar uma instância para do Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi na `Action` `Create` retornar uma instância do model

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new TesteRemoteViewModel());
}
```

E no método chamado pelo `RemoteAttribute` desabilitar a `Cache` usando o atributo `OutputCache`

```
[OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None)]
public JsonResult IsNomeAvailable(string nome, int Id)
{
    //verificar no banco se o nome não é duplicado
    if (true)
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    string suggestedUID = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "O upload {0} já foi cadastrado.", nome);

    return Json(suggestedUID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```